# Dynamic graphic interactions on mobile: HTML5 and Javascript or native application

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, html, graphics

I have to develop a mobile application that displays dynamic generated images and then allows the user to perform different actions by pressing certain region of the image. For example displaying a router and allowing the user to select 2 ports on the router. The ports color should dynamically change when selected.

I'm not really experience with mobile development so I was wondering what are the differences between an HTML5 + javascript solution and a native app. Will a native app give me more flexibility in dealing with graphics? What are the limitation of graphic representation of HTML5 + javascript compared to native apps?

I think I could probably use both technologies but which one is recommended keeping in mind that this functionality is just the beginning. I am sure the product will extend more and there will be more complex graphical interactions to implement in the future.

Thanks,
Irina

Answer (score 0):

- Using HTML5 and JavaScript will be easier compared to native Android or IOS code.
- You can develop once and use it for for multiple devices (android, IOS etc)
- Native will always be faster, even though the JavaScript rendering in mobile devices getting faster.
- With HTML5 and JavaScript you will be limited with the device's browser limitation

  these are the first things come to my mind. You should consider your requirements, costs(time etc...), supports for platforms and many other things before you choose your weapons.